# Speech to text software/dictation program thats worthwhile for researchers?

Tags: publications, writing, software

I tend to be glacially slow in writing up my publications, and I was wondering if it would be worthwhile to invest in a speech-to-text program to dictate my rough drafts. Has anyone had a positive experience with a particular program? My first glance at whats available seemed to suggest Dragon Naturally Speaking, with a dictionary from Spellex might be able to handle the technical language, but I thought I'd ask the community their opinion.

Thanks!

Comment: Although interested in the answer, I believe this might be closed as a shopping question.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Academia.SE and I hope you enjoy your time here. I unfortunately found your question out of scope of this community, but I think you may find an answer for it on other websites of the SE, like https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

> Has anyone had a positive experience with a particular program?

I've been using Dragon Naturally Speaking (called Dragon Professional Individual in its more recent versions) for over a decade on Windows, including during my PhD: not perfect, but it does a good job and I am not aware of any better alternative. Google speech recognition is nowadays more accurate but 1) can't be used with most desktop programs on macOS/Linux/Windows 2) [doesn't](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/244780/12202) allow custom dictionary.

FYI:

- [How can I use Dragon NaturallySpeaking to write LaTeX math formulas by voice efficiently?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/145367/11400)
- [Is there any decent speech recognition software for Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/256138/16704)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! I'll look into it.